# How to handle an Swift error message?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to learn Swift by following the Note example in the O'Reilly book, Learning Swift. I've run into an error message on some code for which I haven't a clue what to do to correct it. The code is taken directly from the book:

```
let ErrorDomain = "NotesErrorDomain"

func err(_ code: ErrorCode,
         _ userInfo:[AnyHashable: Any]? = nil) -> NSError {
    // Generate an NSError object, using ErrorDomain, and using whatever
    // value we were passed
    return NSError(domain: ErrorDomain,
                   code: code.rawValue,
                   userInfo: userInfo)
}
```

Xcode is signaling an error on the return statement. The text of the error is

> Cannot convert value of type '[AnyHashable : Any]?' to expected argument type '[String : Any]?'

It offers to fix the error by inserting `as! [String, Any]` but when I accept that and the line is changed, it now issues a warning. Looking at the definition of NSError, this third parameter is, in fact, supposed to be `[String, Any]`. However, the fact that, after changing the code, I get the warning tells me something still is right, that casting a `[AnyHashable, Any]` to `[String, Any]` is not quite straight forward.

Note I'm using Xcode 9 with Swift 4. I suspect the book was using a prior version in which this code was acceptable.

What's going on here and what should I do to correct this problem?

Comment: If you are starting to learn Swift you should choose a better/newer book. You won't use NSError at all when coding in Swift. I would recommend reading Apple's Swift 4th edition book to start with. https://itunes.apple.com/tr/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-4-0-3/id881256329?mt=11

Answer (score 1):

`NSError.init(domain:code:userInfo:)` expects userInfo to be of type `[String : Any]?` simply change your function signature to reflect this and it should work as intended.

```
 let ErrorDomain = "NotesErrorDomain"

 func err(_ code: ErrorCode,
         _ userInfo:[String: Any]? = nil) -> NSError {
    // Generate an NSError object, using ErrorDomain, and using whatever
    // value we were passed
    return NSError(domain: ErrorDomain,
               code: code.rawValue,
               userInfo: userInfo)
}
```

Comment: You mean `NSError` initializer. `Error` is a protocol and has no initializers.

Comment: @LeoDabus yes! nice catch!